# Trig Sub Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

if given the problem $$\int \frac{(27x^2)}{(4+9x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$ you would use a trig sub of $x = \frac{2}{3} \tan(\theta)$

after solving, I got an answer like this $$\frac{2}{3}(\ln|\frac{3x}{2} + \frac{3\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+x^2}}{2}| - \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+x^2}})$$

I saw on wolfram alpha a similar answer using inverse hyperbolic sin but my course doesn't cover that. I feel as though im missing something is everything okay?

Comment: Sure, why not. You are probably aware that integration with different techniques often leads to equivalent expressions whose equivalence is far from obvious.

Comment: I find something like your answer without $\frac23()$

Comment: you did? what did you get?

Comment: $ln|\frac{3x}{2} + \frac{3\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+x^2}}{2}| - \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+x^2}}$

Comment: how did you cancel out the $\frac{2}{3}$? When I checked it you get 2/3 on bottom and 2/3 on top with both tan and sec. Did you factor and cancel then? $$\int \frac{\frac{2}{3} tan^{2} \theta \frac{2}{3} sec^{2} \theta}{(\frac{2}{3} sec \theta)^{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have$$\int \frac{(27x^2)}{(4+9x^2)^\frac32}dx\\=\frac{27}8\int\frac{x^2}{(1+\frac94x^2)^\frac32}dx\\=\frac{27}8\int\frac{(\frac23tan\theta)^2(\frac23sec^2\theta)d\theta}{sec^3\theta}\\=\int\frac{(tan^2\theta)(sec^2\theta)d\theta}{sec^3\theta}\\=\int(sec\theta-cos\theta)d\theta\\=(ln|\frac{3x}{2} + \frac{3\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+x^2}}{2}| - \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+x^2}})$$